# XHTML manipulation library in Java

Tags: java, html, dom

I am looking for XML/XHTML Java library/framework that can perform the following two tasks for me.

Before going on few definitions:

- `NodeOffset(Node node, int offset)` marks some point in text node in the XML tree.
- `nodeB`, `nodeI`, `nodeP` are the corresponding `Node` instances of the below mentioned XHTML tree and `nodeSpan` is some newly created node (where `Node` is not necessarily `org.w3c.dom.Node` and may be any other abstraction)

#### Flattering XHTML into plain text

The library should be able to produce plaintext output (e.g. by implementing [`CharSequence`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) or similar) from given XHTML and provide one-to-one mapping between chars in the output and original XHTML node tree (e.g. via the function `NodeOffset getNodeOffset(int plainTextOffset)`).

Example: Suppose we have the following XHTML:

```
<p><b>GeForce</b> 9300M GS provides powerful <i>visual computing features</i> to thin and light notebooks.</p>
```

Then the plaintext representation will obviously be:

```
GeForce 9300M GS provides powerful visual computing features to thin and light notebooks.
```

Then e.g.

- `getNodeOffset(0)` should return node `NodeOffset(nodeB, 0)`
- `getNodeOffset(40)` should return node `NodeOffset(nodeI, 5)`
- `getNodeOffset(80)` should return node `NodeOffset(nodeP, 49)`.

I might miss the correct numbers, but I hope, you got the idea. I repeat the example, now with pseudo-markers inserted:

```
|GeForce 9300M GS provides powerful visua|l computing features to thin and light n|otebooks.
```

and

```
<p><b>|GeForce</b> 9300M GS provides powerful <i>visua|l computing features</i> to thin and light n|otebooks.</p>
```

#### Node manipulating

The library should provide a possibility to inject nodes into XHTML, that may span the tree possibly crossing the node boundaries e.g. via the operation `NodeSet insert(Node nodeToInsert, NodeOffset start, NodeOffset end, int mode)`. The function works in two modes:

- *mode1*: Split the node to be inserted if necessary. In this case the splitted from `nodeToInsert` nodes are returned as operations result.
- *mode2*: Close the parent nodes. `nodeToInsert` is returned as is.

For example: the `insert(nodeSpan, NodeOffset(nodeB, 2), NodeOffset(nodeP, 9), mode1)` operation should produce

```
<p><b>Ge<span>Force</span></b><span> 9300M GS</span> provides powerful <i>visual computing features</i> to thin and light notebooks.</p>
```

`insert(nodeSpan, NodeOffset(nodeB, 2), NodeOffset(nodeP, 9), mode2)` operation should produce:

```
<p><b>Ge</b><span><b>Force</b> 9300M GS</span> provides powerful <i>visual computing features</i> to thin and light notebooks.</p>
```

It is analogue to what users do in rich editor:

**Ge**<s>**Force** 9300M GS</s>

I wonder, if there is anything like this in OpenSource world, as I really don't want to re-implement the wheel... I've checked quickly [Open Source HTML Parsers in Java](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers) without success.

When you post an answer:

- Make sure the above mentioned functions are available in library API (provide a link to JavaDoc).
- The library is Java-native (no JNI) and OpenSource.

Comment: I have my own code to do what you requested in the first part, using the default java XML parsers. If I add in the second part, would that be enough to satisfy the request? It's not an external library obviously, just one file with a bit of code :)

Comment: @LightningIsMyName: I hope you've done it in in one file, but not with one class :) as one needs several abstractions. (a) Do you use `org.w3c.dom.*` model or some other model? (b) Will you be able to share your code on SourceForge (or BitBucket/GitHub) and make it OpenSource (LGPL/ASF)?

Comment: Several classes of course :) Yes, it uses org.w3c.dom.* and it can be open-sourced in whatever reasonable license you choose (LGPL sounds good). I'll take that interest as a yes and start working on it

Comment: @LightningIsMyName: Great. Let me know, if you need my help.

Comment: @LightningIsMyName: Perhaps you can push to SCM whatever version you have (even non-working) and provide a link as the answer to this post? You will get a bounty if the code looks perspective :)

Comment: Just to clarify, I don't understand how `getNodeOffset(nodeP, 80)` could ever return `NodeOffset(nodeP, 49)` (or 48). Did you mean `NodeOffset(nodeP, 80)`?

Comment: Everything is now supported, see my answer :)

Comment: @Luc1245: 49 is the offset on the textual representation of `pNode` not including the children. My original post has a minor mistake, as it should be `48 = length(" 9300M GS provides powerful ") + length(" to thin and light n")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrapped code that I had already, with modifications to match your requests (WIP) in an open-source project: [ShtutXML](http://code.google.com/p/lightningismyname-misc/source/browse/trunk/ShtutXML/). It's pretty documented, so I doubt you'll have a problem using it.

The first request (Finding a node and offsets from a global position) is already built in, and splitting of text nodes in the XML is already built in (so you can easily wrap them in new nodes as you wish). Therefore, adding the logic for marking areas with an element is rather trivial. I'll try to do it later, but this is my best effort on this request for now.

On your XML, using my [example program](http://code.google.com/p/lightningismyname-misc/source/browse/trunk/ShtutXML/src/org/shtutxml/Example.java) this is my output:

```
************* BASE DOCUMENT *****************
DOCUMENT ROOT
|-<p >
| |-<b >
| | |-Text: GeForce
| |-Text:  9300M GS provides powerful 
| |-<i >
| | |-Text: visual computing features
| |-Text:  to thin and light notebooks.

*** Text ***
"GeForce 9300M GS provides powerful visual computing features to thin and light notebooks."

*** Node of each text segment ***
[b: null]: GeForce
[p: null]:  9300M GS provides powerful 
[i: null]: visual computing features
[p: null]:  to thin and light notebooks.


*** Offset testing ***
offset 0 is at [b: null] at 0
offset 40 is at [i: null] at 5
offset 80 is at [p: null] at 48
```

Asking it to split the element at the global position 4 will produce

```
*********** Split(4) DOCUMENT *****************
DOCUMENT ROOT
|-<p >
| |-<b >
| | |-Text: GeFo
| | |-Text: rce
| |-Text:  9300M GS provides powerful 
| |-<i >
| | |-Text: visual computing features
| |-Text:  to thin and light notebooks.

*** Node of each text segment ***
[b: null]: GeFo
[b: null]: rce
[p: null]:  9300M GS provides powerful 
[i: null]: visual computing features
[p: null]:  to thin and light notebooks.
```

Of course this syntactical split means nothing for the actual XML code that matches that document, but it will allow wrapping one text part at a time with any other node you wish.

**Edit:** The first insertion mode is already supported

**Edit 2:** The second insertion mode is already supported

**Notes:**

- Any document modification you may do, will make all the offsetts invalid. Using them later will cause corruption of the entire document. So, after each modification you must do GetOffset to retreive the offsetts again.
- I know some of the functions are not documented. Basically the only functions that should be used outside of the package are the ones you requested from the `StrXML` class. More documentation will be added later and you can contact me by email (see my profile page) for questions.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could try [**jsoup** - http://jsoup.org.](http://jsoup.org)

It is an open source Java library distributed under the MIT license. Its source code is available at GitHub.

From the home page:

> jsoup is a Java library for working with real-world HTML.
>   It provides a very convenient API for extracting and manipulating data, using the best of DOM, CSS, and jquery-like methods.

With jsoup you can:

> - find and extract data, using DOM traversal or CSS selectors
> - manipulate the HTML elements, attributes, and text

Here is its Javadoc:  http://jsoup.org/apidocs/

Comment: I've had good success using jsoup on projects that had similar functionality needs in the past.

Comment: @Luc1245: Are you *sure* that jsoup provides the functionality which I need (please, provide a link to the class, that does it), or your answer is only a guess? On later case your answer does not deserve a bounty, sorry.

Comment: Well, it's easy to retrieve (or set) the whole plain text of any element using the `text()` method of the `org.jsoup.nodes.Element` class; but while studying the API docs to post a demo I couldn't find implementations of the other functionalities you require. So now I'm working on another answer

Comment: @Luc1245: The major problem is not to "planify" XML, but also to map from resulting string back to XML tree. See the examples I have provided in my question (do you see any `getNodeByTextOffset()`?). Also for "planification" for simple case you need only a trivial XSLT transformation.

Answer (score 1):

I tried [Jericho](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html) couple of years back it it was deceptively simple to use its API for parsing. I used it for logging into yahoo mail and fetching the contacts from the address book. I sure it can do much more than. The home page mentions one of your requirement "**Flattering XHTML into plain text**" as one of its features. Some of the features which might be relevant to your questions are

- Built-in functionality to extract all text from HTML markup
- The begin and end positions in the source document of all parsed segments are accessible, allowing modification of only selected segments of the document without having to reconstruct the entire document from a tree.

  And its Free open source. (Quoting the site :*You are therefore free to use it in commercial applications subject to the terms detailed in either one of these licence documents*.)

Comment: The same as for other answers: I see the `Renderer` API which allows to convert XML to plaintext. But where is the reverse mapping?